# AMD driver stalls

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, freeze, gpu

I'm having an issue playing Borderlands 2. Basically, after 30 seconds to a minute in-game, the screen will freeze. I'll still hear audio. Sometimes it recovers after a few seconds, but then the same thing will happen a few seconds later. Sometimes there will be a black line that appears very quickly half way down the screen - it's like the screen has fractured as the lower half of the picture splits and judders. The game will quickly minimise (or if it doesn't, ctrl+alt+delete then clicking cancel takes me back into the game for a while, before it freezes again). Looking into event viewer, I have a lot of display warnings saying that "display driver amdkmdap stopped responding and has successfully recovered". I was able to play both Dawn of War and Call of Duty Modern Warfare 3 with no issues. I suspect my graphics card is reaching the end of its life, but is there another reason why this could be happening?

Things I've tried:

- Reinstalling drivers: the last 3 iterations of AMD drivers. No
  changes made a difference
- sfc /scannow. No problems were found
- Turning all graphics settings down in-game. No difference.
- Fully uninstalling drivers with DDU, than manual re-install. No difference.

I'm not overclocking and the GPU is not overheating (max 50°C-ish monitored with MSI Afterburner). I get a decent (>60) framerate and no stuttering or slowdowns until the freezes.

Specs:

CPU: AMD FX-6300

GPU: Radeon R7 260X

RAM: 8GB

OS: Windows 10 x64 Version 1709

Comment: @Ramhound The latest version of Windows. I don't keep up to date with all the windows news so I couldn't tell you which version

Comment: @Ramhound done, OS part updated